# Android layout getting wrapped when keyboard appears

Tags: java, android, fragmentstatepageradapter

In my application I have two tabs, for which I am using `ViewPager`, two fragments are within this view pager. Sometimes when I tap on first tabs fragments `EditBox` keyboard pops, once I am done with the input keyboard disappears. But layout below keyboard region goes blank (White), this is happening sometimes, specially second launch of application. When application is launched from studio for first time issue doesn't appear. But when I launch it through system application by tapping on its `ic_launhcher` issue comes again. What are the possible causes of issue ?

The layout on launch looks like :

[image]

After I click on edit box & edit some text in address filed, when keyboard disappears, layout looks like :

[image]

I am using view pager inside another fragment & using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` by passing a `getChildFragmentManager()`

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        FragmentStatePagerAdapter fragmentStatePagerAdapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new GeneralInfoFragment();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString(context.getString(R.string.all_data), new Gson().toJson(profileResponse));
                        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new ICEFragment();
                        break;
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 2;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return "General Info";
                    case 1:
                        return "ICE";
                }
                return "";
            }
        };
```

Note : Images are erased to protect privacy

Comment: where are the images ?

Comment: show us ur code and screenshots for better understanding...

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Put this code in your manifest file in your activity tag

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|
screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Or

Try this one

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_direction_3);
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(
        android.R.color.transparent);
```

Or

if you have are using a custom theme then add this in your theme

```
 <item name="android:windowBackground">Transparent color </item>
```

Tel me if you still get the issue.

Comment: ,I have tried with your suggestion,but still having the same problem.

Comment: Where u wrote this code..?? you have to write this in view pager activity..

Comment: I did the changes in the activity where I am implementing the view pager but doesn't work.

Comment: Tru using the first solution remove the second.I hope it will help you out.

Comment: I have already tried with the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  but its not work for me.

Comment: I have used scrollview in both two views will that cause any problem..?

Comment: What theme you are using for this activity...?? if you have are using a custom theme then add this in your theme    <item name="android:windowBackground">Transparent color </item>

Comment: No I am using the default theme.

Comment: I have used scrollview in both two views will that cause any problem..?

Comment: Use custom theme..Make it in styles